# Return Access Token for B2C Local Account

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'd like to B2C to return a claim that includes the access token for a local account. Where I'll be able to use the access token to make MS Graph calls to view and edit profile values (e.g. Given Name, PhoneNumber, etc..)

I've found a similar way to do this with Federated AAD accounts and it works (as seen here: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/B2C-Token-Includes-AzureAD-BearerToken)

I've also tried adding (but doesn't work).

```
 <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="idp_access_token"/>
```

As mentioned here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) also didn't work.

My goal is to get an access token so that I can make Graph Calls allowing the user to make profile edits. I was hoping to use the same method for both Federated AAD accounts and Local Accounts (Federated will be read only).

I'm stuck using ASP.NET (.NET Framework), so a lot of current the examples won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can surely **allow profile edits to a user’s profile through Microsoft Graph API by ensuring that proper API permissions are allowed for the concerned app registration that is used as a service principal for authenticating and authorizing the tokens through the application deployed**. Thus, the below **‘delegated’** and **‘application’** permissions regarding the app registration in Azure AD should be as follows: -

[image: MS Graph API Permissions]
[image: MS Graph API Permissions - 2]

Similarly, after **applying the above permissions to Microsoft Graph API, you will need to execute the below query in Microsoft Graph API for updating the below mentioned ‘Employee ID’ in the user’s profile** as shown below: -

Also, the **user ID through which this query is executed needs to have ‘User Administrator’ Azure AD role assignment for this query to be executed successfully. Thus, in this way, through Microsoft Graph API, you can surely allow the user to make profile edits**.

For more detailed information, kindly refer to the below link: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user***

[image: Microsoft Graph API]
[image: Azure AD User profile]